# Regularization of a sum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, regularization

I am computing the partition function of a gluon gas and I have been incurred in the following sum
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty (2k+1)^4\ln(2k+1).
$$
It is clearly divergent. Is there any possible way to renormalize it? E.g., with the Dirichlet regularization, one has
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty (2k+1)^4\rightarrow -\frac{1}{10},
$$
but here there is a logarithm and I guess that something different should be attempted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could start with
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty (2k+1)^n = (1-2^n)\zeta(-n)
$$
Differentiate both sides w.r.t. $n$ and set $n=4$, we have
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty (2k+1)^4 \log ( 2 k + 1 )  = 15 \zeta'(-4) = \frac{45}{4\pi^4} \zeta(5). 
$$